# swift 2 OSX How can I have comboboxSelectionDidChange execute after NSComboBox.stringValue changes?

Tags: macos, swift2, nscombobox

Clicking UI object `NSComboBox` incorrectly executes `comboBoxSelectionDidChange(...)` before it's `.stringValue` changes instead of after as it's name implies. It does same as `.comboBoxSelectionIsChanging`.

How can I have `comboBoxSelectionDidChange(...)` execute after `NSComboBox.stringValue` actually changes?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSComboBoxDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var comboBox: NSComboBox!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.usernameComboBox.delegate = self
    }

    func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        print(usernameComboBox.stringValue)
        // PRE-selected .stringValue = "ITEM 1"
        // POST-selected .stringValue = "ITEM 2"
        // selecting either item prints PRE-selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code below executes exactly the same as any other `NSComboBoxDelegate` notification function. Doesn't make sense but it works.

```
func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let currentSlection = usernameComboBox.stringValue      
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        while true {
            if self.usernameComboBox.stringValue != currentSlection {
                print(self.usernameComboBox.stringValue)
                break
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter way:

```
     func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

    guard let stringValue = usernameComboBox.objectValueOfSelectedItem as? String else { return }
    print(stringValue)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just in case, any other dinosaurs out there like me, using Objective-c, it's NSLog(@"%@", _myComboBox.objectValueOfSelectedItem);